# SQL Query on finding a share within a segment

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query, which finds out the percentage share of the element on a group by of a Binder. The percentage share of the elements will be calculated separately on Zones having Y's and N's. This is the sample input and output.

[image: Here]

I have created the table over here,*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba7a042bb95057ecf04d68f33dbf25af)*

I am not sure of how to do it, Can someone help me out?

Comment: I don't understand how the values are calculated.  Why are the N values always 50%?

Comment: So, if we consider Bind1(Nsegment)= there are only 2 elements(11 and 15), so there percentage share would be 50-50 percent.

Comment: In Bind1(Y segment) we have total 7 elements: 1(occuring twice),17,56,3,2(occuring twice).So, percentage share of 1's would be 2/7(since its occuring twice), 17 would be (1/7) since its occuring once, and so on –

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing this calculation:

```
select t1.*,
       sum(value) over (partition by binder, zones) / sum(value) over (partition by binder)
from t1;
```

Although the desired results are different.

But you want to split it between two columns:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when zones = 'Y'
             then sum(value) over (partition by binder, zones) / sum(value) over (partition by binder)
        end),
       (case when zones = 'N'
             then sum(value) over (partition by binder, zones) / sum(value) over (partition by binder)
        end),
from t1;
```

EDIT:

The expression you want is:

```
( count(*) over (partition by binder, zones, value) / 
  count(*) over (partition by binder, zones)
)
```

You might as well put this in one column, but if you want it in two, you can use `case` expressions as above.

Comment: We want to find the percentage share of an element, within a N or Y segment, on a group by of Binder